# Not sure how flock works. Need some clarification

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptor, flock

I have a bash script that makes a cURL request and writes the output to a file called `resp.txt`.  I need to create an exclusive lock so that I can write to that file and not worry about multiple users running the script and editing the text file at the same time.

Here is the code that I expect to lock the file, perform the request, and write to the text file:

```
(
flock -e 200
curl 'someurl' -H 'someHeader' > resp.txt
) 200>/home/user/ITS/resp.txt
```

Is this the correct way to go about this?  My actual script is a bit longer than this, but it seems to break when I add the `flock` syntax to the bash script.  My understanding is that this creates a subshell that can write to the locked file.  I'm just not sure if I need to add the file descriptor to the curl request like this:

```
curl 'someurl' -H 'someHeader' 200>resp.txt
```

If someone could explain how these file descriptors work and let me know if I am locking the file correctly that would be awesome!

Comment: Why do you pipe the curl response into a file?

Comment: How does your script "break" when you add this?

Comment: Because I need to extract an ID from the response to use in the next request.  Is there a reason I shouldn't do that, or a better way to accomplish the same thing?  Basically I have a few requests that I need to get info from.  I guess I could rewrite some stuff, it's just getting to be a really long line with the cURL request and whatnot.  Can i use a `|` and continue the script on the next line?  I though it had to be on one line.

Comment: If you want curl to write into the lock file then you want `>&200` on the curl command line.

Comment: @EtanReisner, well I'm guessing that because it creates a subshell that some variables that I set within the lock are not accessible to the bash script, but like I said, I'm new to `flock`, and to be honest, I'm new to bash scripting as well.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me *what* broke. Do you get an error? Do kittens eat your face?

Comment: @EtanReisner, well it kind of does.  If there was an error, I would tell you what that is, but there are not errors, so that is that.  One of the requests that I make requires an ID that is returned by the previous request.  That is what is not working.  I'm thinking that if the variable is set in the subshell and the bash script cannot access it, then the second request will not go through as expected due to the fact that it is missing the ID required..

Comment: So the issue is that you cannot read the request out of `resp.txt` when you add the flock? I'm betting `curl` can't write to the file then. Try `>&200` like I suggested in a previous comment to get it to write to the `flock`ed fd. Also, you would not believe how often people leave out the text of error messages they get. My intention was not to insult you there.

Comment: @EtanReisner, gotcha.  No worries, I appreciate the help.  I will see if that works!

Answer (score 17):

`flock` supports a `command` argument (`-c`). You can use the following one liner in your case:

```
flock resp.txt -c "curl 'someurl' -H 'someHeader' > resp.txt"
```

The above command tries to obtain an exclusive (write) lock for `resp.txt`. It waits unless the lock could be obtained if another script has locked the file.

As soon as the lock can be obtained it executes the `curl` command and releases the lock again.

---

If you want to perform multiple commands while obtaining the lock, I suggest to use a lockfile different from the file you are writing to.

Like this:

```
( 
    flock -n 200 || exit 1
    # commands executed under lock 
    sleep 3
    cat <<< 'hello' > test.txt
) 200> /path/to/lockfile
```

The above creates a sub shell `()` and redirects the output of that sub shell to `/path/to/lockfile` using the file descriptor number `200`. The sub shell will inherit the file descriptor 200 from the base shell.

Inside the sub shell flock tries to obtain a lock for file descriptor `200`. after obtaining the lock the following commands get executed.

Comment: This doesn't help if you want the lock held for the subsequent commands though.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, in the question was just a single command was executed. In this case you can use the `-c` command. I can give an example how to use it with multiple commands...

Comment: @hek2mgl, I would appreciate that!  The documentation gives an example similar to what I have in my question, but for a beginner to bash scripting it's difficult to understand because the man page doesn't go very in depth.

Comment: Sorry, I almost forgot that :) ... I'm AFK for a while. Can explain more later ...